# Pushing ViewController with UIScrollView + UIPageControl onto specific page

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have a VC with a scrollview and pagecontrol implemented in it. It has three pages, which are all set up correctly and working fine. What I want to be able to do is have the VC load onto different pages depending on what button a user presses.

In the method the button calls I have

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
vc.pageControl.currentPage = 2;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

When the VC loads, it is loaded onto the correct page (as evidenced by the bubbles at the bottom of the page) but it is displaying the information from page[0]. If I start scrolling, it jumps back to page[0] no matter what I do.

My best guess is that I need to make the VC load to a specific x origin depending on what page I want to display, but I haven't been able to find anything related to this, so I'm quite lost.

Appreciate any help.

EDIT: Here is the code from the VC class. I didn't write this and it is my first time working with PageControl, so I'm trying to learn as I go.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {

    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = TRUE;
    self.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;

    firstPage = [[UIView alloc] init];
    firstPage.tag = 0;

    secondPage = [[UIView alloc] init];
    secondPage.tag = 1;

    thirdPage = [[UIView alloc] init];
    thirdPage.tag = 2;

    pages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstPage, secondPage, thirdPage, nil];

    // Page Control
    self.pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 3;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;

    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageControl];
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// First Page Setup
//
[self setupFirstPage];

// Second Page Setup
//
[self setupSecondPage];

// Third Page Setup
//
[self setupThirdPage];

// Frame everything
//
CGRect screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
CGRect navBarFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;

self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, navBarFrame.size.height, 320, screenFrame.size.height - navBarFrame.size.height);
self.pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenFrame.size.height - 70, 320, 20);

firstPage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
secondPage.frame = CGRectMake(320 * secondPage.tag, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
thirdPage.frame = CGRectMake(320 * thirdPage.tag, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

// Add Subviews
//
[self.scrollView addSubview:firstPage];
[self.scrollView addSubview:secondPage];
[self.scrollView addSubview:thirdPage];

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320 * pages.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
```

Comment: The problem is somewhere in your `ViewController` code. You might need to override the `currentPage` setter to update whatever isn't being updated by initializing it. If you post some more code, it could help.

Comment: I added in code from the VC class. I used arbitrary names for things, but setupFirstPage/SecondPage/ThirdPage are all the same function, just creating labels and placing them where we want them. I do see that a -(void)setPosition function was implemented, but no code had been added to it so it may be possible that is where they were planning on changing the location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this function and calling it right after you set the page number:

```
- (void)pageSelectorChanged 
{
    CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * self.pageControl.currentPage;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dima. I had tried to do something similar, but the scrollRectToVisible is what I was missing.